# Function that stars all but first 3 chars of a word and removes blank space in separate .txt file

Tags: python

takes a copy of a .txt file (the file_name) and then copies but replaces all but the first 3 characters of every word with the character '*' in the destination .txt file. How do I replace all whitespace so each word is followed by a singular space also?

```
def speed_reader(file_name, destination):
    with open(file_name) as wordfile:
        text_str = wordfile.read()
        word_list = text_str.split()
        output = ""
        for word in word_list:
            output += word[:3] + ("*" * (len(word)-3))

    with open(destination, "w") as writefile:
        writefile.write(''.join(output))
```

this is what I have so far.

edit: I just realized I haven't done it correctly looking at the output .txt file.

Comment: `final += " "`?

Comment: Did you mean `output += ...` instead of `final`?

Comment: yes sorry @razdi, keep switching between 2 py files so get them confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close.  It would be easier to create a new list of truncated words, then join them all with a space just before writing the output.

```
def speed_reader(file_name, destination):
    with open(file_name) as wordfile:
        text_str = wordfile.read()
        word_list = text_str.split()
        out = [w[:3]+('*' * (len(w)-3)) for w in word_list]

    with open(destination, "w") as writefile:
        writefile.write(' '.join(out))
```

Answer (score 1):

When replacing characters with stars, add a space to the end of each word.

```
....
    ....
        output = ""
        for word in word_list:
            output += word[:3] + "*" * (len(word)-3) + " "
```